# gradle: No source task ':processTestResources' and ':processtResources'

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

First-time Gradle project user in eclipse, and running a gradle build on the defaault project presents me with this output:

```
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :assemble UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test UP-TO-DATE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 940ms
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
```

Why are two of them 'NO-SOURCE' and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an error. It just means that there is nothing inside `src\main\resources` and `src\test\resources` folder.

If you put some resources like a property file, image etc. that is needed for your application, it should go away.